# Etymology of the expression "happy-go-lucky"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

Where does the expression "happy-go-lucky" come from? What does being lucky have to do with not being worried about anything.

Comment: The relevant [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=happy-go-lucky) entry says ***Earlier as happy-be-lucky (1630s)***. The idea is that a happy-go-lucky person is [cheerfully] unconcerned with such boring things as *caution* and *planning for the future* - because they trust to ***luck***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression “happy-go-lucky” originally meant "haphazard", or "as luck will have it", and only from the late 19th century did it acquire the more common contemporary meaning:

> - ***is an adverb, an adjective and a noun, although the noun is rarely used today.***  A person who is described as “happy-go-lucky” is a generally carefree, laid-back and relaxed soul, taking life as it comes, gazing on the world through  a rosy pink Panglossian haze and blithely unconcerned about the inevitable heart-rending horrors the future holds.
>
>   - The happy-go-lucky person’s motto is “Everything will work out and we’ll all be fine,” an attitude often resulting from seeing way too many Disney movies as a child.
> - Decoding the phrase “happy-go-lucky” seems, at first glance, easy. Here comes a simple-minded chap, skipping happily along on life’s journey, trusting that he’ll be lucky. And that is, in fact, the current sense of the term “happy-go-lucky.”
>
>   - ***But when the phrase first appeared in print in 1672, it meant simply “as luck will have it,” “whatever happens” or “haphazard,” not implying either a happy disposition or a lucky ending.***
> - The phrase “happy-go-lucky,” however, didn’t get the memo and went on meaning “haphazard” up until the early 19th century (“Messrs. Hubbards resisted [the action] on the plea of having sold him ‘happy go lucky’ (meaning the purchaser was to take him with all faults, for better for worse.)” 1802).
>
>   - ***But by the mid-1800s, under the influence of the new, cheerier sense of “happy,” “happy-go-lucky” as an adjective developed its modern sense of “carefree, easy-going” in reference to a person’s personality or behavior (“The first thing was to make Carter think and talk, which he did in the happy-go-lucky way of his class,” 1856).***

From the Word  Detective